# 指定した通りに配列の要素を書き換えたい

Tags: python, アルゴリズム

二次元配列の要素を、別の配列のデータに従って入れ替えたいです。

今、1つの配列に縦5横6の二次元配列があり、配列(array)の中身は全て "." で埋まっています。つまりarrayは

```
array = [
  [".",".",".",".",".","."],
  [".",".",".",".",".","."],
  [".",".",".",".",".","."],
  [".",".",".",".",".","."],
  [".",".",".",".",".","."]  # ←①
]
```

となっています。

この "." を `str_array` 配列の数字に従って書き換えたいです。たとえば `str_array` が

```
str_array = [[1, 1, 0], [1, 3, 2], [3, 3, 1]]
```

のときを考えます。この `str_array` は要素を3つもっています。

- 最初の `[1, 1, 0]` はarrayの最後のブロック（①で示したもの）を書き変えます。

  - `[1, 1, 0]` の 0 は `[".",".",".",".",".","."]` の左から0番目の場所を表し、1, 1 は縦横1つずつの "." を書き換えることを示します。
  - これによって、最後のブロックが `["#",".",".",".",".","."]` になるということです。
- 次の `[1, 3, 2]` は左から2番目の "." を書き換えます。今 array は

  ```
  array=[
      [".",".",".",".",".","."],
      [".",".",".",".",".","."],
      [".",".",".",".",".","."],
      [".",".",".",".",".","."],
      ["#",".",".",".",".","."]
  ]
  ```

  という状態であり、一番下のブロックの左から2番目が空いているので、縦1横3で "#" を敷き詰め、下のように書き換わります。

  ```
  array=[
      [".",".",".",".",".","."],
      [".",".",".",".",".","."],
      [".",".",".",".",".","."],
      [".",".",".",".",".","."],
      ["#",".","#","#","#","."]
  ]
  ```
- 最後の `[3, 3, 1]` は左から1番目の "." を書き換えますが、一番下のブロックには縦横3つをもう入れ替えられないので、

  ```
  array=[
      [".",".",".",".",".","."],
      [".","#","#","#",".","."],
      [".","#","#","#",".","."],
      [".","#","#","#",".","."],
      ["#",".","#","#","#","."]
  ]
  ```

  と array を書き換えます。

最終的に、

```
array=[
    [".",".",".",".",".","."],
    [".","#","#","#",".","."],
    [".","#","#","#",".","."],
    [".","#","#","#",".","."],
    ["#",".","#","#","#","."]
]
```

を出力させたいです。

これを行えるようなアルゴリズムとしてfor文をまず思いつきました。次にスタート "." を入れ替えられるように `4 * 6 + 1` という風に `(縦幅-1) * 横幅 + スタートの順番` という式を使うのではと思いましたが、これらをどう組み合わせればいいのかわかりません。特に "." が既に埋まっていて "#" になっている時とそうでない時で処理が違います。このプログラムはどのように書けますか？

今の断片コードですが、

```
for i in range(len(str_array))
    str_array[0][i] * str_array[1][i] + x
```

(`x`はスタートの順番）と書きました。

Comment: 断片でも構わないので実際のコードを提示することは可能でしょうか。

Comment: はい、断片コードを記載しました。

Comment: これは、array の大きさや str_array の長さも変わりうるということでしょうか？

Comment: array の大きさは変わりませんが、str_array の大きさは変わることもあります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ごく簡単に説明すると、`str_array` で指定された矩形領域を走査して、領域内の要素が全て `'.'` の場合は `'#'` に置き替えています。
以下の実行例では `str_array` に `[5, 1, 5]` を追加しています。なお、エラーチェック(`array` の range check)はしていないので、`str_array` の内容によってはエラーが発生します。

```
str_array = [[1, 1, 0], [1, 3, 2], [3, 3, 1], [5, 1, 5]]

l = len(array) - 1
for str in str_array:
  h, w, s = str  # height, width, start
  for r in range(l, h-2, -1):
    if all(map(all, [[i == '.' for i in array[y][s:s+w]] for y in range(r, r-h, -1)])):
      for y in range(r-h+1, r+1):
        array[y][s:s+w] = ['#'] * w
      break
=>    
[['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#'],
 ['.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#'],
 ['.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#'],
 ['.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#'],
 ['#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '#']]
```

＃ テトリスを想い起こしました

**コメント欄の質問に対する回答**

- `l = len(array) - 1` はどういう意味があるのでしょうか？

`array` の内容を調べ始める位置(インデックス)です。この場合、`array` の最後の要素からチェックする必要があるので、そのインデックス番号を取り出しています。ループ内不変定数になるので、予め変数 `l` に代入していますけれども、`for r in range(len(array)-1, h-2, -1):` としても実際には Python インタープリタで最適化されるのではないかと思います。

- `for r in range(l, h-2, -1):`　で `h-2, -1` としているのはなぜでしょうか？

実際に調べる範囲は `array[l]` から `array[h-1]` で十分だからです。例えば `[3, 3, 1]` の場合、「高さ」が `3` なので、

```
- array[4], array[3], array[2] 
- array[3], array[2], array[1] 
- array[2], array[1], array[0]
```

をチェックする事になります。これ以降(例えば `array[1], ...`)は `array` の領域から外れる(はみ出る)事になります。

- `[[i == '.' for i in array[y][s:s+w]] for y in range(r, r-h, -1)]` の部分は何をしているのでしょうか？

`all()` で判定するため、`'.'` との比較結果(True or False)のリストを作っています。矩形領域内の全ての要素が `'.'` であれば、`'#'` に置き換える事ができるわけです。

- `for y in range(r-h+1, r+1):` の `r-h+1` と `r+1` はどういう意味なのでしょうか？

これは `range(r, r-h, -1)` と同値です。方向が逆になっているだけで、入れ替えても結果は同じになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！何点か質問があります。

Comment: まず、l = len(array) - 1はどういう意味があるのでしょうか？またfor r in range(l, h-2, -1):　で h-2, -1としているのはなぜでしょうか？
次に、if all(map(all, [[i == '.' for i in array[y][s:s+w]] for y in range(r, r-h, -1)])):　の[[i == '.' for i in array[y][s:s+w]] for y in range(r, r-h, -1)]　の部分は何をしているのでしょうか？
最後に、
for y in range(r-h+1, r+1):　のr-h+1と r+1はどういう意味なのでしょうか？